# Apply CSS to a number of divs defined with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an array of strings with variable size.

For each elements in the array I'd like to separately be able to modify the size of the text they contain.

Right now it only works on the first sentence.

I would so something like

```
    #trim <?= $i ?> {}
```

to be able to control each sentence but this doesent work.

What would be the optimal way to do that?

My code is the following:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>
    #trim {
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
       overflow: hidden;
       white-space: nowrap;
       position: relative;
       padding-left:10px;
       width: 50px;
      }
     #trim:after {
       content: '+';
       right: 0;
       position: absolute;
     }
     #trim.full {
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      white-space: normal;
    }
    #trim.full:after {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>


    <?php

        $array=['first sentence','sencond sentence','third sentence'];

        $i=0;

        foreach ($array as $answer)
        {  
        ?>

         <p id="trim"><?= $answer ?></p>

     <?php
     $i++;
    }
    ?>

    <script>
    $('#trim').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('full');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your PHP loop seems to assign `id="trim"` for all the `p` tags. That is not valid. You need to assign a unique `id` for each and set a common `class` for all of them. That would be the easiest way.

Comment: may be put unique ids' in every element, call them by class, and take $(this).attr('id')?

Comment: Or not bother with an `id` at all if you dont need to adderss thes items specifically

Comment: @guest420420 If you have `$(this)` whats the use of `.attr('id')`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did not see the whole context.. Yeah, if you have the object itself, you won't need the attribute normally..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Id must be unique.

**Reason why your code is not working.**

If you are selection an element with id using an `id` selector like `$('#trim')` only first one will be selected.

> *Note: it is always better to use class instead of using same `id`.*

**Working demo using class**

```js
$('.trim').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('full');
});
```

```css
.full{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="trim">Para 1</p>
<p class="trim">Para 2</p>
<p class="trim">Para 3</p>
<p class="trim">Para 4</p>
```

---

You can use attribute selector if you are using `id` with same element. (Just for knowing.)

```
$('[id="trim"]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('full');
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$('[id="trim"]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('full');
});
```

```css
.full{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="trim">Para 1</p>
<p id="trim">Para 2</p>
<p id="trim">Para 3</p>
<p id="trim">Para 4</p>
```

Comment: Better to just use a common class rather than hack around using duplicate ID's

Comment: @charlietfl I am forced to so like this because of the question.

Comment: No you aren't...can suggest OP changes the php so it uses class and or instead of ID and then provide selector `$('.className')`

Comment: Thx for detailed explanation.

Comment: @michltm Always glad to help `:)`

Answer (score -1):

The Id are uniques you can use them once.

Here I use your $i for give it a diferent name each ID.

```
 <p id="trim$i"><?= $answer ?></p>
```